# How do I check for output of tesseract in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, tesseract

I am running a loop in bash script and passing png files to tesseract to read the text of image files. If output of the tesseract ocr shows `Empty page!!` or nothing then I want the loop to proceed to next image. If it does include text then I want to store the output in a text file.

This is what my basic script looks like,

```
for i in {1..100}
do
tesseract file-${i}.png stdout >> result.txt
done
```

Comment: You have a text file that contains the path of the images? and you want to loop through that text file?

Comment: My files names are in number format. For example, file-1, file-2, file-3. All these files are images in png format.

Answer (score 0):

This is roughly what you need. I took the liberty to do an "ls" to list png files in a directory, rather than iterating from 1 to 100:

```
for file in /my/directory/*.png
do
  # Redirect output to a variable. This works even if output is multiline.
  output="$(tesseract "$file" stdout)"
  
  if [ -n "$output" ] && [ "$output" != "Empty page!!" ]
  then
    echo "$output" >> result.txt
  fi
done
```

This is a bit rough, you may want to check result codes from tesseract in case there are errors, or you may want to omit standard error messages, things like that. But this should give you an idea.

Comment: `$(ls /my/directory/*.png)` should be `/my/directory/*.png`. See [Parsing `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: It didn't work. I am getting [ -n: command not found error.

Comment: Good point, I've changed the code to use /my/directory/*.png without the ls command. Now, about the [-n command not found, you need to make sure there is a white space after the [ character. That's the only way I can get the error you are describing.