# How do I ignore "Empty page!!" error that tesseract gives in a loop of files?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, tesseract

I am using a bash script to read text from a lot of image files and I want to skip over files that do not contain anything and gives the empty page error. How can I do that?

This is what my current code looks like,

```
for i in {1..100}
do
tesseract file-${i}.png stdout >> result.txt
done
```

I have image file names like file-1.png, file-2.png, etc.

For files with empty text, I am getting the following error,

```
Empty page!!
```

I just want to skip over such files.

**Edit:**

This is what my image with empty text looks like,

[image]

This is the image with text,

[image]

Comment: You have already asked this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62462879/how-do-i-check-for-output-of-tesseract-in-bash-script ?

Comment: Yeah but didn't get much help from that post so made a new one. Is that against the rules?

Comment: Define what you mean by _file with empty **text**_. According to your description, you are processing **image** files here, so what it an image file with an empty text?

Comment: If there is a problem with the answer you received to your first question, you should comment on that answer before asking the same question again. Otherwise you might get the same answer again. *`Is that against the rules`* it's not strictly forbidden I guess, but users are encouraged to [close your second question as a duplicate of the first one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339624/6770384).

Comment: @user1934428 I have updated my post with image examples like you asked. Please check it out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check for output of tesseract in bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62462879/how-do-i-check-for-output-of-tesseract-in-bash-script)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't

Comment: @RickK.: If only _tesseract_ knows, what an "empty page" is, the only possiblity is to run this program. You can catch the output of _tesseract_, and check whether the message says 'Empty Page!'.